# ROW_NUMBER over column result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

How can I count the number of occurrences in a given column?

Follow this example. With a table like this:

```
+----------+---------+------+
| PersonID |  Name   | City |
+----------+---------+------+
|        1 | John    | NY   |
|        2 | Mohit   | CA   |
|        3 | Jay     | AZ   |
|        4 | Roger   | NY   |
|        5 | David   | NY   |
|        6 | Peter   | AZ   |
|        7 | Ana     | NY   |
|        8 | Irina   | NY   |
|        9 | Michael | NY   |
|       10 | Ken     | AZ   |
+----------+---------+------+
```

How can I achieve this?

```
+----------+---------+------+-------------+
| PersonID |  Name   | City | CityCounter |
+----------+---------+------+-------------+
|        1 | John    | NY   |           1 |
|        2 | Mohit   | CA   |           1 |
|        3 | Jay     | AZ   |           1 |
|        4 | Roger   | NY   |           2 |
|        5 | David   | NY   |           3 |
|        6 | Peter   | AZ   |           2 |
|        7 | Ana     | NY   |           4 |
|        8 | Irina   | NY   |           5 |
|        9 | Michael | NY   |           6 |
|       10 | Ken     | AZ   |           3 |
+----------+---------+------+-------------+
```

Will I have to use ROW_NUMBER function over SUM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's as simple as this.

```
SELECT *,
       cityCounter = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY city ORDER BY personID)
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY personID
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you just want to enumerate the values for each city and then sort by `id`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by city
                                order by personid) as CityCounter
      from table t
     ) t
order by personid;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the result by using row_number() analytic function but there is no over SUM?
You can read [online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) documentation about using row_number() and its correct syntax.

In your case, you want to number the occurrences of each city which means you need to group by City (partition by City), then you need to give a logic to your ordering, which city line should be first, is it when the personID comes first?

Your row_number would then looks like the following:

```
row_number() over(partition by city order by personID)
```